# A formula for the refractive index of a gas dependent on temperature and pressure

Tags: temperature, pressure, optical-properties

I am in search for a formula that gives me the refractive index of a gas at a given temperature and pressure. Does such a formula exist? Ideally the solution should have this form:

$n_g(t, p) = \ldots$,

where $n_g$ is the refractive index of the gas $g$, $t$ is the temperature and $p$ is the pressure.

Comment: n(g)-1=k* density, the k factor is called Gladstone-Dale coefficient. You can always look up gas density in the literature tables. https://books.google.com/books?id=HWtB2R0gWFgC&pg=PA26&dq=refractive+index+of+a+gas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPrerS4-3hAhUPnKwKHSyhC6MQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=refractive%20index%20of%20a%20gas&f=false